# Notepad++ IntelliSense - How to?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I'm looking for a good IntelliSense solution for Notepad++. Does anyone know a good plugin?

Comment: For what language?

Comment: For HTML 4/5 & CSS 2/3

Comment: Have you tried the built-on Auto-Completion functionality of Notepad++?

Comment: Yeah, but I nowhere near as good as you'd expect.

Comment: some fingertext snippets: 1. [finger text snippet: html & js](https://bitbucket.org/netpie/fingertext-snippets/src%20)
2. [various snippet](https://github.com/mreq/FingerText-snippets/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know FingerText is closest to VS Intellisense solution for notepad++ https://github.com/erinata/FingerText